# Jenkins with Git

Tags: jenkins-plugins

When trying a Jenkins plugin I am developing, I want to use an example project. As this example project is versioned by git, I want to use git for this project.

Unfortunately, when running Jenkins with git it giving me error like
GitException: cannot fetch origin repository from git.

Is there any workaround for this, that I can use the with the git plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is two way to install git into Jenkins

1.install as plugin

Jenkins -> manage Jenkins ->  install

2. download hpi and upload as plugin

Jenkins -> manage Jenkins -> advanced ->upload plugin

please check screenshot[image: Step 1![][1]]